# Finding boundaries of figure in 2d array

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a figure that is represented by 1 values that are “connected” vertically, horizontally or diagonally in a 2 dementional array.
I need to save the index of the boundary of the figure (the row and column of the 0's that are connected to the figure, in any type of c++ container.

For instance, in the following 2d array, I should get the following indexes:
`(0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (1,2), (1,4), (1,5), (2,2), (2,3), (2,5), (2,6)...` etc.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What is the most efficient way to do so, on both space and time complexity?

Comment: do you mean `minimizing` instead of `maximizing`?

Comment: The problem can be solved with a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Normally, a flood fill keeps track of the 1s that have been seen by adding them to a `queue`. You'll need to do that, and in addition, you'll need to keep track of the neighboring 0s, adding them to any convenient container, e.g. a `vector`. So, for example, when processing the 1 at index (1,3), you'll add the 1 at index (2,4) to the `queue`, and add the seven neighboring 0s to the output `vector`.

Comment: @ddorda: Has your question been answered correctly? If yes, it would be great if you could accept the answer. This will allow the community to mark other similar questions as duplicate. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257089/fast-way-to-find-border-cells-in-a-2d-array

Answer (score 1):

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, vector<vector<int>>& boundary, int rows, int cols, int i, int j){
    if(!isValidCoordinate(i, j))
        return;
    
    if(isAnyNeighborOne(i, j)){
        boundary.push_back({i, j});
        matrix[i][j] = 2;
    }
    else
        matrix[i][j] = 3;

    //Explore eight directions
    /* I didn't bother about x = 0 and y = 0. 
     * You can, if you want.
     * Doesn't make a difference though. 
     */
    for(int x = -1; x < 2; x++){
        for(int y = -1; y < 2; y++){
            dfs(matrix, boundary, rows, cols, i + x, i + y);
        }
    }
}

vector<vector<int>> getBoundary(vector<vector<int>>& matrix){
    vector<vector<int>> boundary;
    int rows = matrix.size();
    if(!rows)
        return boundary;
    int cols = matrix[0].size();
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
                dfs(matrix, boundary, rows, cols, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return boundary;
}
```

[image]

[image]

- If you print the matrix at the end, you'll see the boundary with `2`.
- Whatever you see as `3`, if you want, you can set it back to `0`.
- `isValidCoordinate()` and `isAnyNeighborOne()` is left to you as an exercise.
- I use `vector<vector<int>>` for boundary. You can try using `vector<pair<int,int>>` as well.
- With the above solution you'll get inner boundary as well as outer boundary. As an exercise, you can try only inner boundary or only outer boundary.
- You can solve the same problem with BFS as well. If the matrix is of large size, stack might overflow due to recursive calls. Better to prefer BFS in such cases.
- Time and space complexity of the above solution is `O(rows * cols)`.