# Fast Way to Find Border Cells in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose that I have a n x n 2D array where the entries are either 0 or 1. For example:

```
[[0, 1, 1]
 [1, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

Now I want to find the neighbor cells of the 1s in the array, which are the cells to the sides and directly diagonal of the 1s in the array that equal to 0. So in the example above, the neighbor cells would be {(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)}. There is the brute-force method of doing this, where I iterate through every entry and if it is a 1, I look at its neighbors and check if it equal to 0. For large n with a high density of 1s, the number of checks made is around 8n^2. However, I feel like I can make use of the redundancy of this problem to come up with a faster solution. For example, after look at the first entry in the cell (0, 0), I see that that it has two neighboring ones and a neighboring 0. So I know that I don't have to check the cell (1, 1) and its neighbors. I also know that at (0, 1) and (1, 0) the entry is 1, so I can add (0, 0) as a neighbor cell.

What's the fastest implementation of a solution to this problem that someone can come up with for this problem? Personally, I've thinking of using some sort of BFS or DFS implementation, but I'm not sure how I would implement it. I was thinking instead of taking around 8n^2 checks, it would only take around n^2 checks.

(Also, I don't know if this is a leetcode problem. It seem suitable to be one, so if anyone knows the name or number of this problem on leetcode, please let me know!)

Comment: If you don't have any other information about the input I believe this will always take `O(n^2)` (because you need to check every cell at least once just to know where are the ones). So, maybe you could lower the `8` in the `8n^2` but it will be insignificant, it will still be `O(n^2)`

Comment: Oh yes, that’s kind of what I was hoping for. For the constant to be lower. I know the complexity can’t be better than O(n^2), but I was wondering if the actual number of checks can be a lot lower than 8n^2. I was thinking if it can be done in around n^2. I’ll edit my question to make it clearer, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947896/finding-boundaries-of-figure-in-2d-array/63948234#63948234

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni that question's answers uses dfs, which is a good algorithm and solves the problem but as you can see for each position the 8 neighbor checking is obligatory, so it is almost the same.

Comment: I think an approach that might reduce runtime, but not overall time complexity is: Create a duplicate of the first matrix, traverse this second matrix and whenever you encounter a 1 at the original matrix at current position, set value of all neighbour cells to 1 without doing any checks (so you get rid of all if conditions, which should increase the performance), subtract your original matrix from this duplicate matrix and if final value of a cell in this duplicate matrix > 0, it was originally a 0 who had a neighbour 1.

Comment: Though, curious why do you want to bring 8n^2 to n^2?

Comment: I’m making an AI for a game similar to go, this just helps speed it up. A factor of 8 can make a huge difference.

Comment: @IUissopretty If you are making this for a game, always keep a mask matrix for this purpose in the memory, and when a player performs a move update neighbour cells immediately. After each played move you just need to update 8 neighbour cells and you can use the mask whenever you need.

Comment: Yes, that would if everything is in sequence, but for my case, I just need to assume that all I’m given is a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can think of an idea that will lower the `8`.

First you sum all the numbers int the matrix, that will gives you how many 1s there are in the matrix. This step can be made in `O(n^2)`.

Then if there are less 1s than `(n * n) / 2` you do the check by the 1s. I mean you go for every item and if it is a 1 you look for all the 0 positions in the eight neighbor (and add them to your answer).

In the other side, if there are more 1s than `(n * n) / 2` you do the same but this time you do the check by the 0s. You go for every item and if it is a 0 you look for at least one 1 in the eight neighbor. If there is a 1 neighbor you add to your answer the current 0 position.

Why doing this? Well you are checking the 8 neighbor at most `(n^2)/2` so the final time in the worst case will be: `n^2 + n^2 + 8(n^2)/2` = `2n^2 + 4(n^2)` = `6n^2`

Ps: Thanks to @unlut that pointed some error this answer had

Comment: Counting number of 1s is O(n^2) because you have to traverse all elements of NxN array, also you are checking the 8 neighbors of "at most" (n^2)/2 elements, not at least.

Comment: Also overall complexity would be n^2(counting number of 1s) + n^2(you are traversing the matrix again to find 1s/0s to check their neighbour) + 8(n^2)/2 (checking 8 neighbours of decided cells) = 6n^2.

Comment: Oh you are right counting the 1s are n^2 but it is a separated so it will be added not multiplied....the other thing is true is "at most" that was my English sorry about that hahhaha

Comment: Yeah i get your point...thanks for commenting. I give you some credits :)

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking instead of taking around 8n^2 checks, it would only take around n^2 checks.

I think this is impossible. It all depends on input. For every 1, you must check/overwrite neighbors. So, minimum of `number of 1s in input matrix * 8` checks are required.

Try out some examples

```
0 0 0        1 1 1        0 1 0        1 0 1
0 1 0        1 1 1        1 1 1        0 0 0
0 0 0        1 1 1        0 1 0        1 0 1
```

Comment: Yeah but he could count how many 1s or 0s are there and use that info to know how to check and low the 8 to a 4...check my answer...i did comment he that it will be still O(n^2)

Comment: @JorgeMorgado: Agreed. Though OP is interested to bring it down to n^2 only, which is impossible. There will always be a constant c greater than 1 for c * n^2 checks.